# How can I catch send meeting action before to create the meeting in outlook/office365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

I need to catch the action over "send" button in office365 or outlook, the main idea is to pass this action for rules to verify if the user can create or not the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the admin mailbox as the booking request delegate, who can accept or decline the meeting request.

[Create and manage room mailboxes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-room-mailboxes#delegates)